# Accidentally accepted unknown IP to Desktop Sharing

Tags: security, remote-desktop, remote-access

I was using Desktop Sharing on 12.04 for some days, and there were a lot of connect requests from unknown IPs. One of the connect requests I accidentally agreed to because I mixed up the Agree-Deny-buttons.

I quckly cancelled the connection, but I was wondering whether a few seconds of this could possibly get my computer infected somehow, maybe leave some backdoor open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as soon as they had access they could have retrieved something malicious and executed it. I would recommend running, 'sudo lsof -i' to see what network connections/ports are open and that should give you some pointers as to if they dropped a listener of some kind.